# Angularjs ReferenceError: function is not defined

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i am getting `ReferenceError: findId is not defined` this the code

```
var app = angular.module('sample', ['ngRoute', 'ngStorage']);
app.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/noteTemp', {
            templateUrl: 'noteTemp.html',
            controller: 'MainCtrl'
        })
        .when('/newNote', {
            templateUrl: 'newNote.html',
            controller: 'MainCtrl'
        })
        .when('/newNote/edit/:id', {
            templateUrl: 'newNote.html',
            controller: 'MainCtrl'
        })
        .otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/noteTemp'
        });
});
app.factory('StorageService', function ($localStorage) {
    
    $localStorage = $localStorage.$default({
        things: [   { id: 1, time: 'Oct 17, 2020 9:34:41 AM', message: '#hello world' },
        { id: 2, time: 'Oct 17, 2020 9:34:41 AM', message: 'COMPLETE THE IP PROJECT' },
        { id: 3, time: 'Oct 17, 2020 9:35:45 AM', message: '#hello world3' }]
    });
    var _getAll = function () {
        return $localStorage.things;
    };
    var _add = function (thing) {
        var updatedItem = findId(thing.id);
        if (updatedItem) {
            updatedItem.date = thing.date;
            updatedItem.message = thing.message;
        } else if(thing.message===""){
            
        } else {
            thing.id = newId();
            $localStorage.things.push(thing);
            
        }
        
    }
    var _remove = function (thing) {
        $localStorage.things.splice($localStorage.things.indexOf(thing), 1);
    }
    
    return {
        getAll: _getAll,
        add: _add,
        remove: _remove,
        findId: function(id) {
            for (var item in $localStorage.things) {
                if ($localStorage.things[item].id === id) {
    
                    return $localStorage.things[item];
                }
            }
        },
        newId:  function() {
            if (NewId) {
                NewId++;
                return NewId;
            } else {
                var maxId = _.max($localStorage.things, function(thing) {
                    return thing.id;
                });
                NewId = maxId.id + 1;
                return NewId;
            }
        }
    };
});
app.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, $routeParams, StorageService, $location) {
    $scope.things = StorageService.getAll();
    
    if (!$routeParams.id) {
        $scope.newContent = { id: 0, time: new Date(), message: '' };
    } else {
        $scope.newContent = _.clone(noteService.findId(parseInt($routeParams.id)));
    }

    $scope.add = function () {
        StorageService.add($scope.newContent);
        $location.path('/noteTemp');
    };
    $scope.remove = function (thing) {
        StorageService.remove(thing);
        $location.path('/noteTemp');
    };
});
```

i think the error is i cant call a functions within the factory,
also i wanted to ask whether should i use service instead of factory.....
this is all the details i have please accept the question .
.why am i not able to post this question is my important doubt...please acccept.....

Comment: findId() is undefined because it is out of scope. Try moving findId() into _findId like you have it with _getAll/_add/_remove, and define it before _add where it is used so it'd be in scope.

Comment: @JonathanRosa i actually had it that way first ,but that didnt work so i changed it like this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the calling context is reliable, you can refer to `this` to get the returned object, and from that, get to the `findId` property on the returned object:

```
var _add = function (thing) {
    var updatedItem = this.findId(thing.id);
```

If the calling context isn't reliable, define `findId` as a standalone function beforehand:

```
function findId(id) {
    for (var item in $localStorage.things) {
        if ($localStorage.things[item].id === id) {

            return $localStorage.things[item];
        }
    }
}
// ...
return {
    getAll: _getAll,
    add: _add,
    remove: _remove,
    findId: findId,
```

Comment: sorry im new to asking questions.i marked the check box.the upvote shows i need 15 reputations like that